React project doesn't compile in CI pipeline because of missing dependency in useEffect Hook (runs fine in local deployment)
I get this error message:

src/questions/QuestionComponent.tsx   Line 22:8:  React Hook useEffect
has a missing dependency: 'setWorkdayAnswer'. Either include it or
remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

The purpose of the code concerning the problem is that I have checkboxes from Monday to Friday and every time any checkbox gets hit, the state information of all checkboxes should be sent to the backend via postWorkdayAnswer().
Then I do npm start everything works fine, no bugs in executing the frontend whatsoever, but if run npm run build I get the above error, which prevents my CI pipeline to build successfully.
This is the code:
import { Question, TimeAnswer, TimeUnit, WorkdayAnswer } from "../service/models";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { getTimeUnitList, postTimeAnswer, postWorkdayAnswer } from "../service/apiService";
import TimeAnswerProperties from "./TimeAnswerProperties";
import "./QuestionComponent.css"
import { convertTimeUnitToMinutes } from "../utilities/Util"

interface QuestionProps {
  question: Question
  answers: Array<TimeAnswer>
  answerCallback: () => void // refreshing site
}

export default function QuestionListComponent(props: QuestionProps) {
  const [timeUnitList, setTimeUnitList] = useState<Array<TimeUnit>>([])
  const [currentTimeAnswer, setCurrentTimeAnswer] = useState<string>()
  const [workdays, setWorkdays] = useState<boolean[]>([true, true, true, true, true, false, false]);**
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("")

  useEffect(() => {
    setWorkdayAnswer();
  }, [workdays]);

  const setWorkdayAnswer = () => {
    const workdayAnswer: WorkdayAnswer = {
      questionId: props.question.id,
      question: props.question.question,
      monday: workdays[0],
      tuesday: workdays[1],
      wednesday: workdays[2],
      thursday: workdays[3],
      friday: workdays[4],
      saturday: workdays[5],
      sunday: workdays[6],
    };

    postWorkdayAnswer(workdayAnswer)
      .then(() => props.answerCallback()) // refreshing site
      .catch(() => {
        console.error("Error posting workday answer:", Error);
        setErrorMessage("error posting answer");
      })
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadTimeUnitList = async () => {
      try {
        const data = await getTimeUnitList();
        setTimeUnitList(data);
      } catch {
        setErrorMessage("Failed to load time unit list")
      }
    };

    loadTimeUnitList();

    const currentAnswer = props.answers.find(answer => answer.questionId === props.question.id)
    setCurrentTimeAnswer(currentAnswer ? currentAnswer.time : "00:00");
  }, [props.answers, props.question.id])

  const setTimeAnswer = (timeInMinutes: number) => {
    const timeAnswer: TimeAnswer = {
      questionId: props.question.id,
      question: props.question.question,
      timeInMinutes: timeInMinutes
    }

    postTimeAnswer(timeAnswer)
      .then(() => props.answerCallback()) // refreshing site
      .catch(() => {
        console.error("Error posting time answer:", Error);
        setErrorMessage("error posting answer");
      })
  };

  const timeUnitsToChoose = timeUnitList
    .filter(timeUnit => {
      if (!props.question.previousQuestionId) {
        return true;
      } else {
        const previousQuestionAnswer = props.answers.find(answer => answer.questionId === props.question.previousQuestionId)
        if (previousQuestionAnswer) {
          const currentTimeAnswerInMinutes = convertTimeUnitToMinutes(currentTimeAnswer);
          return (
            timeUnit.timeInMinutes! >= previousQuestionAnswer.timeInMinutes) &&
            timeUnit.timeInMinutes !== currentTimeAnswerInMinutes;
          } else {
            return true;
          }
        }
      }
    )
    .map(timeUnit => <TimeAnswerProperties key={timeUnit.id} timeUnit={timeUnit}/>)

  const renderWorkdayCheckboxes = () => {
    const days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];
    return days.map((day, index) => (
      <span key={index}>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          id={`check${index}`}
          checked={workdays[index]}
          onChange={event => {
            const newWorkdays = [...workdays];
            newWorkdays[index] = event.target.checked;
            setWorkdays(newWorkdays);
          }}
        />
        <label htmlFor={`check${index}`}>{day}</label>
      </span>
    ));
  };

  const QuestionType = () => {
    if (props.question.question === "On which days do you work ?") {
      return (
        <div>
          {renderWorkdayCheckboxes()}
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <select
            className="questionAnswer"
            name={props.question.type}
            id={props.question.id}
            onChange={event => setTimeAnswer(Number(event.target.value))}
          >
            value=<TimeAnswerProperties
              key={currentTimeAnswer}
              timeUnit={{
                time: currentTimeAnswer + "",
                length: 15,
                end: "24:00"
              }}
            />
            {timeUnitsToChoose}
          </select>
        </div>
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="question">
      <p>{props.question.question}</p>
      {errorMessage && <div>{errorMessage}</div>}
      {QuestionType()}
    </div>
  );
}

I did try adding setWorkdayAnswer as a dependency in
useEffect(() => {
  setWorkdayAnswer();
}, [workdays]);

which causes weird bugs that days are not being saved right are the last one is missing or something like that.
I also tried adding setWorkdays, which also causes weird bugs.
Solution:
Parent Component "Question.tsx" with useCallback after Drew's feedback:
import {NavLink} from "react-router-dom";
import {useEffect, useState, useCallback} from "react";
import {getQuestionList, getTimeAnswer} from "../service/apiService";
import QuestionListComponent from "./QuestionComponent";
import {Question, TimeAnswer} from "../service/models";
import "./Questions.css"


export default function QuestionList() {

    const [questionList, setQuestionList] = useState<Array<Question>>([])
    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("")
    const [answers, setAnswers] = useState<Array<TimeAnswer>>([])

    useEffect(() => {
        getQuestionList()
            .then(data => setQuestionList(data))
            .catch(() => setErrorMessage("questionList doesnt load"));
    }, [])

    const onAnswer = useCallback(() => {
/*         getQuestionList()
            .then(data => setQuestionList(data))
            .catch(() => setErrorMessage("questionList doesnt load")); */
        getTimeAnswer()
            .then(data => setAnswers(data))
            .catch(() => setErrorMessage("timeAnswer doesnt load"));
    }, []);

    const questions = questionList.sort((s1, s2) => s1.order - s2.order).map(question => <QuestionListComponent
            key={question.id} question={question} answers={answers} answerCallback={onAnswer}/>)

    return (
        <div className="body">
        <div className="questions">
            <h1 className="questionHeadline"> Questions:</h1>
            {errorMessage && <div>{errorMessage}</div>}
            {questions}

            <br/>
            <br/>

            <NavLink to={"/timetable"}>
                <button className="createButton">create</button>
            </NavLink>
        </div>

        </div>
    )
}

fixed "QuestionComponent.tsx":
import {Question, TimeAnswer, TimeUnit, WorkdayAnswer} from "../service/models";
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {getTimeUnitList, postTimeAnswer, postWorkdayAnswer} from "../service/apiService";
import TimeAnswerProperties from "./TimeAnswerProperties";
import "./QuestionComponent.css"
import {convertTimeUnitToMinutes} from "../utilities/Util"

interface QuestionProps {
    question: Question
    answers: Array<TimeAnswer>
    answerCallback: () => void //refreshing site
}

export default function QuestionListComponent(props: QuestionProps) {
    const [timeUnitList, setTimeUnitList] = useState<Array<TimeUnit>>([])
    const [currentTimeAnswer, setCurrentTimeAnswer] = useState<string>()
    const [workdays, setWorkdays] = useState<boolean[]>([true, true, true, true, true, false, false]);
    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("")

    const question = props.question
    const answerCallback = props.answerCallback

    useEffect(() => {
      const workdayAnswerDbUpdate = () => {
        const workdayAnswer: WorkdayAnswer = {
          questionId: question.id,
          question: question.question,
          monday: workdays[0],
          tuesday: workdays[1],
          wednesday: workdays[2],
          thursday: workdays[3],
          friday: workdays[4],
          saturday: workdays[5],
          sunday: workdays[6],
        };

        postWorkdayAnswer(workdayAnswer)
          .then(() => answerCallback()) // refreshing site
          .catch(() => {
            console.error("Error posting workday answer:", Error);
            setErrorMessage("error posting answer");
          });
      };

      workdayAnswerDbUpdate();
    }, [answerCallback, question, workdays]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const loadTimeUnitList = async () => {
            try {
                const data = await getTimeUnitList();
                setTimeUnitList(data);
                } catch {
                    setErrorMessage("Failed to load time unit list")
                }
            };

            loadTimeUnitList();

        const currentAnswer = props.answers.find(answer => answer.questionId === props.question.id)
        setCurrentTimeAnswer(currentAnswer ? currentAnswer.time : "00:00");
    }, [props.answers, props.question.id])

    const timeAnswerDbUpdate = (timeInMinutes: number) => {
        const timeAnswer: TimeAnswer = {
            questionId: props.question.id,
            question: props.question.question,
            timeInMinutes: timeInMinutes
        }
        postTimeAnswer(timeAnswer)
            .then(() => props.answerCallback()) // refreshing site
            .catch(() => {
                console.error("Error posting time answer:", Error);
                setErrorMessage("error posting answer");
                })
    };

    const timeUnitsToChoose = timeUnitList
        .filter(timeUnit => {
            if (!props.question.previousQuestionId) {
                return true;
            } else {
                const previousQuestionAnswer = props.answers.find(answer => answer.questionId === props.question.previousQuestionId)
                if (previousQuestionAnswer) {
                    const currentTimeAnswerInMinutes = convertTimeUnitToMinutes(currentTimeAnswer);
                    return (
                        timeUnit.timeInMinutes! >= previousQuestionAnswer.timeInMinutes) &&
                        timeUnit.timeInMinutes !== currentTimeAnswerInMinutes;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        })
        .map(timeUnit => <TimeAnswerProperties key={timeUnit.id} timeUnit={timeUnit}/>)

       const renderWorkdayCheckboxes = () => {
           const days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];
           return days.map((day, index) => (
               <span key={index}>
                   <input
                       type="checkbox"
                       id={`check${index}`}
                       checked={workdays[index]}
                       onChange={event => {
                           const newWorkdays = [...workdays];
                           newWorkdays[index] = event.target.checked;
                           setWorkdays(newWorkdays);
                       }}
                   />
                   <label htmlFor={`check${index}`}>{day}</label>
               </span>
           ));
       };

       const QuestionType = () => {
           if (props.question.question === "On which days do you work ?") {
               return (
                   <div>
                       {renderWorkdayCheckboxes()}
                   </div>
               );
           }

           else{
               return(
               <div>
                   <select
                       className="questionAnswer"
                       name={props.question.type}
                       id={props.question.id}
                       onChange={event => timeAnswerDbUpdate(Number(event.target.value))}
                   >
                              value=<TimeAnswerProperties
                              key={currentTimeAnswer}
                              timeUnit={{
                                time: currentTimeAnswer + "",
                                length: 15,
                                 end: "24:00"
                              }}
                              />
                              {timeUnitsToChoose}
                   </select>
               </div>
               );
           }
        };

    return (
        <div className="question">
            <p>{props.question.question}</p>
            {errorMessage && <div>{errorMessage}</div>}
            {QuestionType()}
        </div>
    );
}


setWorkdayAnswer is missing as a useEffect hook dependency since it's an external (to the hook callback) reference. workdays is indirectly a dependence since setWorkdayAnswer depends on it.
You've a few options:

Memoize setWorkdayAnswer on workdays, answerCallback, and question as dependencies via useCallback and use setWorkdayAnswer as the useEffect hook dependency
const { answerCallback, question } = props;

...

const setWorkdayAnswer = useCallback(() => {
  const workdayAnswer: WorkdayAnswer = {
    questionId: props.question.id,
    question: props.question.question,
    monday: workdays[0],
    tuesday: workdays[1],
    wednesday: workdays[2],
    thursday: workdays[3],
    friday: workdays[4],
    saturday: workdays[5],
    sunday: workdays[6],
  };

  postWorkdayAnswer(workdayAnswer)
    .then(() => props.answerCallback()) // refreshing site
    .catch(() => {
      console.error("Error posting workday answer:", Error);
      setErrorMessage("error posting answer");
    });
}, [answerCallback, question, workdays]);

useEffect(() => {
  setWorkdayAnswer();
}, [setWorkdayAnswer]);


Move setWorkdayAnswer into the useEffect callback body to eliminate it as an external dependency.
const { answerCallback, question } = props;

...

useEffect(() => {
  const setWorkdayAnswer = () => {
    const workdayAnswer: WorkdayAnswer = {
      questionId: props.question.id,
      question: props.question.question,
      monday: workdays[0],
      tuesday: workdays[1],
      wednesday: workdays[2],
      thursday: workdays[3],
      friday: workdays[4],
      saturday: workdays[5],
      sunday: workdays[6],
    };

    postWorkdayAnswer(workdayAnswer)
      .then(() => props.answerCallback()) // refreshing site
      .catch(() => {
        console.error("Error posting workday answer:", Error);
        setErrorMessage("error posting answer");
      });
  };

  setWorkdayAnswer();
}, [answerCallback, question, workdays]);


Just apply the fetching logic directly.
const { answerCallback, question } = props;

...

useEffect(() => {
  const workdayAnswer: WorkdayAnswer = {
    questionId: props.question.id,
    question: props.question.question,
    monday: workdays[0],
    tuesday: workdays[1],
    wednesday: workdays[2],
    thursday: workdays[3],
    friday: workdays[4],
    saturday: workdays[5],
    sunday: workdays[6],
  };

  postWorkdayAnswer(workdayAnswer)
    .then(() => props.answerCallback()) // refreshing site
    .catch(() => {
      console.error("Error posting workday answer:", Error);
      setErrorMessage("error posting answer");
    });
  };
}, [answerCallback, question, workdays]);



Note that if answerCallback is passed down as a prop that it should also be memoized and passed as a stable reference. In the parent you would also use the useCallback hook for this.
Example:
const answerCallback = useCallback(() => {
  // ... callback logic
}, [/* appropriate dependencies */]);

...

return (
  ...
  <QuestionListComponent
    answerCallback={answerCallback}
    ...
  />
  ...
);


Hello Drew, thank you very much ! All three solutions fix the first problem, but now I still get React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'props'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. However, 'props' will change when *any* prop changes, so the preferred fix is to destructure the 'props' object outside of the useEffect call and refer to those specific props inside useEffect  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps  as an error.

Destructuring the props still shows that the now more specific dependecies are missing. If I add props.question.id, props.question.question, props.answerCallback() as dependencies I get weird bugs again.

@Gregor499 Ah, good to hear my suggestions work for you. Sorry I missed the other dependencies, they should be added as well. What weird bugs are you seeing now? I'm guessing that at least answerCallback should be provided as a stable reference from the parent so updated my answer to note that. Can you provide additional details?

Alright thanks, just adding the props broke the time-answer checkboxes because they depend on each other (the answer of the first one always sets the minimum of the next one) and the props let the page refresh to often I think (did also crashed my backend, by firing to requests continuosly). I needed to actually destruct the props before the useEffect-hook like: const question = props.question     const answerCallback = props.answerCallback otherwise with e.x. props.question he still wants all props as dependency.

And without using "useCallback" as a memorizer as you suggested, it would refresh too often again. I added it without any dependency though, because I didnt know which one works

@Gregor499 I think in most usual cases using props.X as a dependency will work, but maybe not every prop is stable in your case. I've updated my answer to reflect destructuring the individual props to be used as dependencies.

How does the useCallback hook works properly without a dependency ? Isnt it running constantly then ?

@Gregor499 It would only recompute each render cycle if you omitted the dependency array entirely, otherwise, an empty dependency allows the hooks to run once, and a populated dependency array triggers the hook any time any of the dependencies change.
